# Simple yes/no loop in C

Tags: c, loops

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to do simple C program, with y/n loop for filling an array and getting sum/average/number of entries/min and max value, but all I get are zeros at the end. Any tips would be helpful, below is the code. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        int N, Number, i= 0,j=0, c;
        double sum, average, min, max;
        double array[N];
        double arr[100];
        char YesNo = 'y';
        int count = 0;
        printf("Please enter maximum size of the array: ");
        scanf("%d",&N);
        while(1){
                printf("Do you want to enter a number? ");
                scanf("%c",&YesNo);
                //if(YesNo != 'Y' || YesNo != 'y' || YesNo != 'n' || YesNo != 'N'){
                //printf("Please enter y or n ");
                //break;
                //return 0;}
                if(YesNo =='y' || YesNo == 'Y'){
                        printf("Enter number: ");
                        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
                        array[i]=arr[j];
                        i++;
                        count++;
                        j++;
                }
                if(YesNo =='n' || YesNo == 'N'){
                        break;
                }
        }
        max = arr[0];
        for (c = 1; c < count; c++) {
                if (arr[c] > max)
                {
                        max = arr[c];
                }
        }
        min = array[0];
        for (c = 1; c < count; c++)
        {
                if (array[c] < min)
                {
                        min = array[c];
                }

        }

        for (i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
                sum = sum + arr[i];
                average = sum/count;
                Number = count;
        }
        printf("\n Sum is: %f",sum);
        printf("\n Number of elements is: %d", count);
        printf("\n Average is: %f ", average);
        printf("\n Maximum is %f",max);
        printf("\n Minimum is %f",min);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double array[N];` What is the value of `N` there?

Comment: It's unclear what your asking.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: `scanf("%f", &array[i]); array[i]=arr[j];` That looks backwards.

Comment: Also give a whitespace before `%c` as this will consume new line char left in buffer when you press the ENTER kwy .`scanf("%c",&YesNo);` --> `scanf(" %c",&YesNo);`

Answer (score 0):

array[N] will probably be a 0 sized array as N was not set.

After reading in the value into array[i], you then do:

```
array[i]=arr[j];
```

so whatever was in array[I], now equals what is in arr[j], which since wasn't set to anything will be 0.

The other loops using arr will also be 0 result as arr is never set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with the code you mentioned. **Firstly** here

```
int N;
double array[N];
```

what is the `N` value ? Since `N` is not initialized it may takes junk data & tries to create array of that many elements which causes **undefined behavior**. So first define the `N` value. for e.g

```
#define N 5
```

Or makes these below two statements
printf("Please enter maximum size of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
before declaring `array`. For e.g

```
int N;
printf("Please enter maximum size of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
double array[N];/* this works if compiler supports VLA */
```

**Secondly**, when you do
`array[i]=arr[j];`what `arr[j]` contains ? It's garbage. So do like

```
arr[j] = array[i];
```

as `array[i]` contains the data user has scanned.

Also consider the use case like, Lets assume user enter `N` as `5` and if user is pressing `y` inside `while(1)` more than `5` times than accessing out of boundary data in array cause **undefined behavior**. For e.g lets consider below code

```
int N;
printf("Please enter maximum size of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&N); /* let say 5 */
double array[N]; /* max you can store 5 elements */
while(1){ /* it breaks when user press n or N */
   printf("Do you want to enter a number? ");
   scanf(" %c",&YesNo); /* what if user didn't press n or N after 5 times, loop doesn't break which makes array[i] going out of bound */
   if(YesNo =='y' || YesNo == 'Y'){
      scanf("%f", &array[i]); /* this cause problem if user has press y or Y more than N(5) times */
      arr[j] = array[i];
      /* some code */
    }
}
```

Lastly for finding average

```
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
       sum = sum + arr[i];
       average = sum/count;
       Number = count;
}
```

why performs `average = sum/count;` `count` times, as it makes operation, instead do `average = sum/count;` only one time after calculating `sum`. For e.g

```
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
       sum = sum + arr[i];
}
average = sum/count; /* do only once */
Number = count;
```

**Sample code**(Modified based on your code)

```
int main(void) {
        int N=0,i=0 ,c=0;
        double sum, average, min, max;
        printf("Please enter maximum size of the array: ");
        scanf("%d",&N);
        double array[N];
        double arr[N];
        char YesNo = 'y';
        int count = 0;
        while(count < N) {
                printf("Do you want to enter a number? ");
                scanf(" %c",&YesNo);

                if(YesNo =='y' || YesNo == 'Y'){
                        printf("Enter number: ");
                        scanf("%lf", &array[count]);
                        arr[count]=array[count];
                        count++;
                }
                else
                        break;
        }
        max = arr[0];
        for (c = 1; c < count; c++) {
                if (arr[c] > max)
                {
                        max = arr[c];
                }
        }
        printf("max ele in array : %lf \n",max);
        min = array[0];
        for (c = 1; c < count; c++) {
                if (array[c] < min)
                {
                        min = array[c];
                }
        }
        printf("min ele in array : %lf \n",min);
        for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
                sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
        average = sum/count;
        printf("Avg of array elements : %lf\n",average);
        return 0;
}
```